# can't get the value of $stateParams in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to get the value of `$stateParams` in my `controller` but it is always **undefined** but I can see there is a value in my `view`.

[image: stateparams value in view]
As you can see there are values on each `link`.

**app.js**

```
   .state('app.help', {
        url: '/help',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/help.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.help-replies', {
        url: '/help/:id',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/help-replies.html'
          }
        }
  })
```

**html view**

*this is the where the lists of data displays*

```
  <div ng-repeat="x in helpData">
    <a class="row responsive-xs" href="#/app/help/{{x.id}}">
      <div class="col"><h6>{{x.subject}}</h6></div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

*this is where the single view of the `clicked` data in the above `view`.*

```
 <div class="row responsive-xs" ng-init="viewHelpAndReplies()">
      <div class="col">
        <h5>Subject: {{$scope.help_id}}</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**controller.js**

```
  $scope.viewHelpAndReplies = function(){
    console.log($stateParams.id);
  }
```

Comment: Did you inject `$stateParams` in controller? Also you haven't identified  a controller for either state shown

Comment: yes I have it injected

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ui-sref to pass data

```
  <div ng-repeat="x in helpData">
    <a class="row responsive-xs" ui-sref="app.help-replies({id: x.id})">
      <div class="col"><h6>{{x.subject}}</h6></div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

and retrieve id with

```
$scope.id = $stateParams.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I got what I needed. But I am not sure if this is good, but for me it is okay because it works.

Here's what I do:

I change the `href`

```
href="#/app/help/{{x.id}}"
```

into `ng-click` and create a `function`

```
ng-click="doViewHelp({id:x.id})"
```

and create `function` in my **controller.js:**

```
$scope.doViewHelp = function(data){
   $state.go('app.help-replies');
   // some codes...
}
```

Thanks.